# Unable to lacate the 'Like' button in instagram using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I developed an Instagram bot using selenium and python. I am facing issue when trying to 'Like' an image.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")

username_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
username_box.clear()
username_box.send_keys('--------')

sleep(1.5)
password_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
password_box.clear()
password_box.send_keys('-------', Keys.ENTER)

        # Open Profile Page
sleep(4)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/-------/?hl=en')
sleep(4)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/Cf930RDM6LO/")
sleep(2)
like_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '//svg[@aria-label = "Like"]')
like_button.click()
```

I have tried x-paths (absolute and relative), class name, but I am unable to locate the 'Like' button and get this message:

```
Message: Unable to locate element
```

I have already tried to seek help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945081/selenium-instagram-bot-clicking-the-like-button).

The HTML part :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aJBs.png)

i try to use from class name of find and click like button but i have problem  :
Pict1 : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDVY7.png)

Pict 2 : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XylKz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You said you have already tried to locate the element with its class name but since you did not share what exactly you did, I have to recommend you this:

```
like_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_ab6-")
like_button.click()
```

Comment: if i user class name for find like button i have problem , i added in question